# I can't see my background image in the 3D view

Tags: 3d-view, image

I try to set up an image as background for a basic blender tutorial,
but it isn't visible.

This is the image I try to have as background:

[image]

Comment: Using an Image Empty might be a solution...

Answer (score 36):

> #Background images will only be displayed in:

> 1. Camera Prespective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)

> 2. Any of the **preset** Orthographic views:

> Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Crl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)

> Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Crl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)

> Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Crl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

You're in perspective mode instead of [orthographic mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html?#perspective-orthographic)  (see the upper left hand corner, it has the abbreviation "persp"). Toggle into orthographic view by pressing <kbd>numpad 5</kbd>.

Also, the view information at the top left shows you are in right view, and the background image settings at bottom right show that the image is set to appear only in left view. For that, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>numpad 3</kbd> to go to left view or change the background image axis to *Right* to make the background image appear in right view.

The image used must be in [a format that Blender supports](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html#supported-graphics-formats). For example, a .gif file will not be displayed.

Comment: It looks like there is an error in the tutorial.

Comment: I'm on a Mac and it's interesting that, with an emulated numpad, Numpad 0 does nothing. Ctrl + Alt + 0 from Ray's answer worked for me, though.

Comment: Background Image also does not appear in Camera View if you are in Local View mode. Toggle back the Global View with NumpadSlash (/) key.

Answer (score 4):

As answered by Pisurquatre "use Camera Perspective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)".

Adjust your scene, in viewport, to your liking.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to set the camera to this view.
Select in 'View' the 'Lock Camera to View' option.
In the 'Background Images'option, where you have 'Left' selected, instead select 'Camera'.

While in this view, you will be able to adjust the scene AND see the background, too.

Answer (score 3):

That was my problem, but I tried hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 3</kbd> or + <kbd>numpad 1</kbd>. I just did that then it showed up. But, make sure you are in orthographic view, just hit <kbd>numpad 5</kbd> to toggle between orthographic and perspective view.

Comment: Lutfi, toggling the numpad-5 key does not turn the display on and off, though depending upon the angle of the view in the viewport, it might be visible in some views in perspective mode, but not others. The numpad-5 key toggles between orthographic and perspective view. To turn the display of the grid on or off, open the properties shelf of the 3D viewport, and in the "display" pane, the item "grid floor" toggles display of the grid on and off.

Comment: @brasshat He probably means that Numpad-5 toggles the visibility of the background image (because it is only visible in orthographic mode).

Comment: Stacker, you may be right, but in his original answer he explicitly referred to "grid". I attempted to improve what he wrote to reduce the chance of misleading another user .