# Background image not displaying

Tags: image

I set a background image (below) but it's not displaying while editing, and yes I'm not in ortho mode.  Any ideas?  Also attached a screenshot.

**Update**: this above part is now answered in comments—you must be in one of the preset ortho views or the camera view, and not the general ortho view or the perspective view.

I'm also interested in making this show up in my Cycles render, but it's not showing up despite having checked the Transparent checkbox under the Film panel.

Threads I've already read include:

- [How do I set a background image while I am editing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing)
- [Background image is not displaying in rendered mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode)
- [I can't see my background image in the 3D view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14315/i-cant-see-my-background-image-in-the-3d-view)

[image]
[image]

Comment: see also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode

Comment: @cegaton Can you re-read my question / see the screenshot?  It was through these and other existing questions that I even got as far as I did.

Comment: Background images will only show on **Orthogonal** preset views: Front/Back, Left/Right and Top/Bottom or on the **camera perspective view**.

Comment: I've answered one of my own questions—what the other threads/answers didn't specify was that you not only could not be in ortho mode, **you can't be in perspective mode either**, and you must instead be in camera view (or one of the top/left/front views).  However, still not seeing the image show up in the render, despite having checked the Transparent checkbox.

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/background_images.html?highlight=background%20image

Comment: To clarify on @cegaton's comment which I found misleading—*you can't just be in any ortho mode* (and the other answers say as much as well), it must be one of these "preset" views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32225/discussion-between-yang-and-cegaton).

Answer (score 1):

## Background images will only be displayed in:

1. Camera Prespective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. Any of the **preset** Orthographic views:

   Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)

   Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)

   Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

To toggle between Prespective and orthogonal view use <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>