# How do you see the background image?

Tags: modeling, image

I am using a Macbook and am learning from this tutorial at 6:50 [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtSh4Yedafg)

However, I cannot see the jpeg image that I set as the background. I tried switching perspectives using the [NUMBERPAD5] shortcut but it still does not work.

Comment: show us a capture of the right panel in the background image section to see if you did something wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [background-image-not-displaying](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42231/background-image-not-displaying/42402#42402)