# VSE channel 0 as background of a scene

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want the film I edit in the VSE to be the background of a scene to move objects inside a real moving landscape or to make a title. What settings ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To preview your clip in the 3D viewport, set it as a background image/movie.

[image: Add movie as background]

To render your scene, add the scene as a layer in the VSE above your movie clip. Set the scenes blend mode to **alpha over**.

[image: Scene with alpha over]

Alternatively to the VSE you could combine your clip and 3D scene in the compositor. It is the same principle.

[image: Scene with alpha over as nodes]

Comment: Note that setting an "image as background" in the viewport doesn't make the image renderable, it used for reference only. Read related posts: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14316/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334

Comment: Thanks for these two options.  It helps me. I understand my mistake. I cannot choose the movie from the VSE. I must look for in the folder of the strip file and load it.

I want to move along the timeline with the bar time and see, as background of the 3D view, the current frame (from channel 0 of the VSE) even if I move on another strip. The background changes automatically at every strip.